# Cant iterate through dataloader object when working with chexpert dataset

Tags: python, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, artificial-intelligence, pytorch-dataloader

Im trying to train a model with chexpert dataset and ive created a class for the chexpert dataset and fed it through the data loader, but when I try to iterate through the dataloader the code just keeps running forever.

```
# This Python 3 environment comes with many helpful analytics libraries installed
# It is defined by the kaggle/python docker image: https://github.com/kaggle/docker-python
# For example, here's several helpful packages to load in 

import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)

# Input data files are available in the "../input/" directory.
# For example, running this (by clicking run or pressing Shift+Enter) will list the files in the input directory

import os
print(os.listdir('../train'))

# Any results you write to the current directory are saved as output.

import sys

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch import optim
import cv2
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision

from fastprogress import master_bar, progress_bar
from matplotlib.image import imread

from PIL import Image

train_data, val_data = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.1, random_state=2019)
class CheXpert(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, path_image, finding="any", transform=None):
        self.dataframe = dataframe
        # Total number of datapoints
        self.dataset_size = self.dataframe.shape[0]
        self.finding = finding
        self.transform = transform
        self.path_image = path_image

        if not finding == "any":  # can filter for positive findings of the kind described; useful for evaluation
            if finding in self.dataframe.columns:
                if len(self.dataframe[self.dataframe[finding] == 1]) > 0:
                    self.dataframe = self.dataframe[self.dataframe[finding] == 1]
                else:
                    print("No positive cases exist for " + finding + ", returning all unfiltered cases")
            else:
                print("cannot filter on finding " + finding +
                      " as not in data - please check spelling")
        self.PRED_LABEL = [
            'No Finding',
            'Enlarged Cardiomediastinum',
            'Cardiomegaly',
            'Lung Opacity',
            'Lung Lesion',
            'Edema',
            'Consolidation',
            'Pneumonia',
            'Atelectasis',
            'Pneumothorax',
            'Pleural Effusion',
            'Pleural Other',
            'Fracture',
            'Support Devices']

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = self.dataframe.iloc[idx]

        img = Image.open(os.path.join(self.path_image, item["Path"]))
        img = np.asarray(img)
        if len(img.shape) == 2:
            
            img = img[:, :, np.newaxis]
            img = np.concatenate([img, img, img], axis=2)
       
        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)

        # label = np.zeros(len(self.PRED_LABEL), dtype=int)
        label = torch.FloatTensor(np.zeros(len(self.PRED_LABEL), dtype=float))
        for i in range(0, len(self.PRED_LABEL)):

            if (self.dataframe[self.PRED_LABEL[i].strip()].iloc[idx].astype('float') > 0):
                label[i] = self.dataframe[self.PRED_LABEL[i].strip()].iloc[idx].astype('float')
                
        print(img)
        print(label)
        return img, label, item["Path"]#self.dataframe.index[idx]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.dataset_size
normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                     std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    CheXpert(train_data, path_image='../train', transform=transforms.Compose([
                                                                transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                                                transforms.RandomRotation(15),
                                                                transforms.Resize(256),
                                                                transforms.CenterCrop(256),
                                                                transforms.ToTensor(),
                                                                normalize
                                                            ])),
    batch_size=48, shuffle=True, num_workers=12, pin_memory=True)
dataiter = iter(train_loader)
print(dataiter)
images, labels = dataiter.next()
print(type(images))
print(images.shape)
print(labels.shape)
```

I have tried several ways of iterating through the dataloader and none of them work